# Classic Asp server.scriptTimeout replacement

Tags: asp-classic

I am working on classic asp script, which when create file button is clicked creates an excel report. Problem is sometimes report is too big and it times out. Due to following code:

```
<%
Server.ScriptTimeout = 200
%>
```

One way to solve this issue is just increase the time. That will be very easy solution. But i want to know from some asp experts if there is any other efficient solution to this problem?

Comment: If you'll post your code maybe we can help you optimize it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider having the database do the work, instead of the page, using DTS or [SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454802/what-is-the-ssis-package-and-what-does-it-do). Or you can [launch a Stroed Proc](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=KB;EN-US;Q252987&) from your page.